# Index.php is stuck with name of site Name magento 2

Tags: magento2

I get the name of Site glue with name odf Site like this : Siteindex.php and i can't get my admin url. error 404 not found on this server

Comment: Can you explain more about your question?

Comment: i put my project on amazon virtuelle machine and i put on web/unsecure/base_url the  url of my sserver then name of project like this : http://ec2-35-165-167-215.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/Site

Comment: Do you have any folder like Site? under var/www/html?

Comment: yes i have this folder

Comment: when i try to click on register i get this link and 404 not found : http://ec2-35-165-167-215.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/Siteindex.php/customer/account/create/?SID=f2n757e2s1elk2sodulstginr3

Comment: rename the Site to site and check the permissions of that folder as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86270/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-developper-magento).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of rename the directory name from Site to site and use the below url as **base_url** in **core_config_data** table:

> http://ec2-35-165-167-215.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/site/

Don't forget to add slash(/) at the end of the url. Also check the permssions of the folder correctly.

Finally run the following commands:

```
magento_root php bin/magento setup:upgrade
magento_root php bin/magento setup:di:compile
magento_root php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

If the site is in developer or default mode then add -f otherwise remove it.